# javascript function never returns true, do you know why?

Tags: javascript, object, if-statement, map-function

I wanna test if a field exist within a map function. If the field exist, it should assign a value to a variable, if not, it should assign an empty string to it. It never change the condition to true even if an object exist (msg variable is always empty). Do you know why?

```
Object.keys(editorJSON).map((key) => {
if (editorJSON[key].name === "Frage") {
    const message = () => {
      if (typeof editorJSON[key + 1] !== "undefined") {
        const msg = editorJSON[key + 
        1].data.chatbottext;
        return msg;
      } else {
        const msg = "testantwort";
        return msg;
      }
    };

}
```

Thank you very much, very appreciate your help

Comment: is it the string `"undefined"` or actually `undefined`

Comment: How about the keys, are they numbers? If so, `key + 1` won't probably be what you think it is, because keys are always strings. Also notice, that you never call the function, and even if you would, you're not returning anything from the actual callback.

Comment: Is the name Frange, what happens when it is not?

Answer (score 0):

```
const message1 = function(){
      if (typeof editorJSON[key + 1] !== "undefined") {
        const msg = editorJSON[key + 
        1].data.chatbottext;
        return msg;
      } else {
        const msg = "testantwort";
        return msg;
      }
    }();
```

And please make sure that your `editorJSON[key + 1]`actually contains a string with the content "undefined", instead of the value `undefined`.